# postgresql queries give error when inserting arrays with strings

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a simple query intended to insert a row into a table of my postgresql 9.5 database:

```
client.query('INSERT INTO "GRIDs" (idname, status, playerid, playerready) VALUES (\'' + gameRoomID + '\', 0, ARRAY[\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\'], ARRAY[0,0,0,0]);', function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
        throw new Error('Error inserting game room ID ' + gameRoomID);
    };
});
```

However, for reason unknown, the string array (ARRAY[\'\',\'\',\'\',\'\']) causes the error, since if I delete it from the query along with the respective playerid column, the query works fine. I've tried the following variations, all with the same result:
ARRAY["\'\'","\'\'","\'\'","\'\'"] (surround each value with double quotes)
ARRAY["","","",""](only use double quotes)
ARRAY[,,,](just empty)
and various similar notations of the curly braces, but those seem to be annoying even with the numbered arrays, so I tend to avoid those.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message, and what is the data type of the `playerid` column?

Comment: Manual query escaping is always a recipe for disaster. You should rely on automatic query formatting from the library. Check out [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t), it can format arrays of anything (including mixed content) automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are arrays of strings you have to declare your type.

Also either use dollar quoting or double your quotes.

```
 ARRAY[''''::text, '''''', ...]
```

Note that your database driver should be doing this escaping for you.  Doing this yourself is a good recipe for sql injection issues.

Comment: Thank you very much. Dollar quoting it (resulting in ARRAY[$$\'\'$$,$$\'\'$$,$$\'\'$$,$$\'\'$$]) solved the problem. Since the table was already creating using pgAdmin and the columns were already of data type character varying[], assigning types to each value was not necessary.